# What is 'void (*old_sigint_handler)(int)'?

Tags: c, syntax

This is a syntax question. I came across the line:

```
void (*old_sigint_handler)(int);
```

And I have no idea what it is doing. It seems like the concatenation of three types with no variable name. I would appreciate clarification!

Comment: function pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns `void`

Comment: Its a pointer to a function that takes a `int` argument and has no explicit return.  [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) is a great resource to clarify this sort of declaration

Comment: It is in the middle of the main method though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void (*old_sigint_handler)(int);
```

This defines `old_sigint_handler` to be a  pointer to a function which takes an `int` and returns `void`, i.e, no value. The parentheses around `old_sigint_handler` are necessary here else the following:

```
void *old_sigint_handler(int);
```

declares a function `old_sigint_handler` which takes an `int` and returns a pointer to `void` type. This is because of the precedence rules in `C`. Parentheses bind tightly to the indentifier `old_sigint_handler` than the `*` making it a function rather than a pointer to a function. Read this to mentally parse complex C declaration - [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: Thou downvoter, I expect you to teach me what I did wrong, not just downvote. There's no point to it.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) to know what declaration it is exactly. It is `C -> English`

`declare old_sigint_handler as pointer to function (int) returning void`

Comment: also, the link is useful

Answer (score 1):

Is a function pointer, to a function with signature `void (int)`

Answer (score 1):

Thats a variable declaration for the variable named old_sigint_handler, that can hold a function pointer to a function that takes an int and returns nothing (void).

Answer (score 1):

It's a declaration of a function pointer named old_sigint_handler that takes a single int and returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a declaration for a function pointer named `old_sigint_handler` to a function that takes an `int` and returns `void`.